# TestNG: unable to provide class level parameter

Tags: testng

I want to provide class level parameter in testng.xml.

Please can someone suggest if that is possible (or possible workaround). I am currently getting below error in doing so:

> "The content of element type "classes" must match
>   "(class*,parameter*)"

```
<classes> 
<parameter name ="P1" value="V1"/> 
<class name="someclass1" /> 
<parameter name ="P1" value="V2"/> 
<class name="someclass2" /> 
</classes>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml):

> Parameters are scoped. In testng.xml, you can declare them either under a `<suite>` tag or under `<test>`.

At the opposite, [the DTD](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php) allows parameters on `<classes>` node but the parser is complaining because you don't respect the order of nodes.

BTW, it is not possible to have a specific value for each class in the same `<test>` node.
In other words, you will have to make many `<test>` nodes:

```
<suite>
  <test>
    <classes> 
      <class name="someclass1"/> 
      <parameter name="P1" value="V1"/> 
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test>
    <classes> 
      <class name="someclass2"/> 
      <parameter name="P1" value="V2"/> 
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: can you tell how to get the value of the variable P1 using the context variable ? i would be highly obliged .... :)